# assign const char* inside nested struct (c++)

Tags: c++

im trying to assign a const char* value inside a nested structure. I want to assign the name and firstname to a char value, not to a string. this is more c i know, but im using c++.
Here is my problem:

```
struct person {
    const char* name;
    const char* firstname;
};


struct person_struct {
    int pers_num;
    struct person* data;
};

// How does the assignment work?... i know this is wrong:
char name[100] = "Jason";
char firstname[100] = "Conner";
struct person_struct pers_info;
pers_info.pers_num = 1;
pers_info->data->name = new char[strlen(name)+1];
pers_info->data->firstname = new char[strlen(firstname)+1]
```

Thanks so much for your help, all of you!!!  :-)

[EDIT:]

Error:

```
error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before â.â token
error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before â->â token
error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before â->â token
```

Comment: You haven't allocated any memory for `person_struct->data`.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but why are you using pointers to characters for strings? C++ have a very good string class in [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream).

Comment: You should also check your use of `->` versus `.` for member selection.

Comment: @Joachim: i know, but i have to use it this way :(

Comment: Why are you using `struct person* data;` instead of `person* data;`?

Comment: Since you are new here, if you post a question regarding build errors, you should always include the actual (unedited and complete) error log in the question. Please *edit your question* to include the errors, it really helps us understand what's wrong. Just saying "it's wrong" or "it doesn't work" will leave us guessing, often badly.

Comment: @Zsolt: i want to get the information inside struct person also from struct struct_person.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: sorry... i posted my error log now

Comment: I meant, you can just omit the `struct`, and write `person* data;` as data member, and have the very same result.

Comment: but then i have to change the structures, right?

Answer (score 1):

[strdup()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strdup.html) would be one approach (to keep it within plain C)

Of course first you need to allocate a sufficient number of person structs

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct person_ {
  const char* name;
  const char* firstname;
} person;

struct person_struct {
  int pers_num;
  person* data;
} PS;



int main(void) {
  char name[100] = "Jason";
  char firstname[100] = "Conner";

  PS.pers_num=1;
  // added cast here 
  PS.data = (person*)calloc(PS.pers_num, sizeof(person));
  PS.data[0].name = strdup(name);
  PS.data[0].firstname = strdup(firstname);

  puts(PS.data[0].name);
  puts(PS.data[0].firstname);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before

Comment: i get: error: invalid conversion from âvoid*â to âperson*

Comment: i want to use this code inside a c++ program, so im compiling with g++

Comment: `âvoid*â to âperson*` - You're doing some weird stuff somewhere that is not in this code. Where do those special characters come from?

Comment: @HagenGeneros a C++ program can have some source files in C and some source files in C++  (although `main()` must be in a C++ file)

Comment: @dornhege that's due to g++ using non-ascii quote marks in its output; the characters you see here are UTF-8 artifacts. (don't ask me why someone thought that was a good idea)

Answer (score 0):

The compilation error is because you wrote `pers_info->data`  ; but `pers_info` is not a pointer. The `->` operator only works with pointers. You meant `pers_info.data`.

However this whole setup is awful.  Use `std::string` to store a string. And make `data` be not a pointer. Then all the memory allocation is taken care of, and you can focus on making the code do what you want it to do.